# Como se hacen restricciones en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, lista, atributos

Tengo este codigo para generar una tabla

```
Create table "Socio"
(
    "Dni" Char(20) NOT NULL,
    "Correo" Char(40),
    "Nombre" Char(20),
    "Contrase_a" Char(20),
    "Puntos" Numeric Check (puntos >=0),
primary key ("Dni")
) Without Oids;
```

Y me da el error

```
ERROR:  no existe la columna «puntos»
HINT:  Probablemente quiera hacer referencia a la columna «Socio.Puntos».
```

Cuando lo corrijo me da otro error

```
ERROR:  falta una entrada para la tabla «socio» en la cláusula FROM
```

Comment: la columna Puntos empieza con letra mayuscula. Prueba escribir Puntos con P Mayuscula en el check

Comment: Ocurre exactamente lo mismo, los dos errores

Comment: Hola, tal vez te ayude lo siguiente, para restringir que no se inserten valores negativos puedes utilizar `UNSIGNED` este convierte cualquier negativo en 0, ejemplo `CREATE TABLE 'NewTable' (
'id'  int UNSIGNED NULL
);` espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Al parecer las restricciones `constraints` son ignoradas en mysql. [Revisa esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522026/how-do-i-add-a-check-constraint-to-a-table)

Comment: La restricción `CHECK`  es ignorada silenciosamente por MySQL, esto fue [reportado como un bug ya en 2004](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3464). Lo explica también [este artículo. Allí mismo te muestran varias formas de solventar ese escollo.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-check-constraint/). También [puedes referirte a este otro artículo](https://mysqlserverteam.com/new-and-old-ways-to-emulate-check-constraints-domain/) donde se dice prácticamente lo mismo que en el anterior.

Comment: En caso que pueda usar MariaDB (>= 10.2.1), entonces, sí tendrá soporte: [CREATE TABLE :: Constraint Expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#constraint-expressions).